# Filter with type on generics type

Tags: scala

I have the following code (simplified):

```
sealed trait Funding {
  id: Int
}

final case class FlatRate(id: Int, days: Int, amount: BigDecimal) extends Funding
final case class PerItem(id: Int, amount: BigDecimal, discount: BigDecimal) extends Funding

final case class AppliedFunding[+A <: Funding](
  person: String
)
```

I have some code that returns a list of "generic" `AppliedFunding` and I would like to get a specific `AppliedFunding` with the correct type. Pseudo-code:

```
val allFunding: List[AppliedFunding[Funding]] = <...>
val flatrateFunding: List[AppliedFunding[FlatRate]] = allFunding.someMagicFunction
```

In place of `someMagicFunction` I am looking for a way to filter the correct `AppliedFunding` instances out and return them with the specific type. I can do `allFunding.collect { ... }`, but no matter what I tried it would still return `List[AppliedFunding[Funding]]`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

below are 2 ways how to do it. Just a sideremark: `collect` is one of the very few situations where `PartialFunction`is a good thing

```
sealed trait Foo
final case class Bar(i:Int) extends Foo
final case class Baz(d:Double) extends Foo

final case class Container[F <: Foo](s:String, f:F) 


val all:List[Container[Foo]] = List(
  Container("bar", Bar(3)),
  Container("bar", Bar(4)),
  Container("bar", Bar(5)),
  Container("bar", Bar(6)),
  Container("bar", Bar(7)),
  Container("baz", Baz(1.5)),
  Container("baz", Baz(2.5)),
  Container("baz", Baz(3.5)),
  Container("baz", Baz(4.5)),
  Container("baz", Baz(5.5))
  )


val bars:List[Container[Bar]] = all.collect { case Container(s, Bar(i)) => Container(s, Bar(i))}
val baz:List[Container[Baz]] = all.foldRight(List.empty[Container[Baz]]) (
    (elem, lst) => elem match {
      case Container(s, Baz(d)) => Container(s, Baz(d)) :: lst
      case _ => lst
    }
  )

println(bars)
println(baz)
```

Comment: err you can probably formulate the case matches a bit more elegant but I was a bit lazy. sorry :D

Comment: You could try something like `all.collect { case c @ Container(_, _: Bar) => c }`, this is a bit shorter, and you don't have to invent more variable names. Whether this is really that much clearer: I don't know, I actually find your first solution sufficiently concise.

Comment: I'm always confused by `@` matches since I have never used them but this seems like the case to do so. thanks!

Comment: @AndreyTyukin https://scalafiddle.io/sf/olgyRJh/2 actually it seems to infer `Container[Foo]` :|

Comment: Oh, you're right. Ok, then I retract my non-working proposal. Your solution is the best (not only that: it is actually *correct*) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution on how this can be done with help of `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf`. Another working solution is provided by Dominic in other answer, but for filtering use case I am not sure that creating a new case class instance for each item which passes the filter is a proper way to go. Moreover, desugaring with `scalac -print` shows that `isInstanceOf` invocation is not going anywhere in that case, it will be embedded in generated `isDefinedAt` and `applyOrElse` methods for the partial function used in `collect`.

Some people say that using `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf` is a code smell but for me it looks that in this particular case usage is safe and correct and brings no single benefit over the solution with `collect`: invocation of `collect` just hides `isInstanceOf` in the generated source code and instantiating new case classes instances is a trade off for a safe call of `asInstanceOf` on a filtered collection.

Also please pay attention that I've added a `funding` field to the `AppliedFunding` case class. I think that having `AppliedFunding` instances without embedded info about funding itself is not very useful anyway.

```
object Test {
  sealed trait Funding {
    val id: Int
  }

  final case class FlatRate(id: Int, days: Int, amount: BigDecimal) extends Funding
  final case class PerItem(id: Int, amount: BigDecimal, discount: BigDecimal) extends Funding

  final case class AppliedFunding[+A <: Funding](
    person: String, funding: A)

  val allFundings: List[AppliedFunding[Funding]] = List(AppliedFunding[FlatRate]("alex", FlatRate(1, 10, 100)), AppliedFunding[PerItem]("christian", PerItem(2, 100, 10)))

  def flatRatePredicate[A <: Funding](appliedFunding: AppliedFunding[A]): Boolean = appliedFunding.funding.isInstanceOf[FlatRate]

  val flatRateFundings: List[AppliedFunding[FlatRate]] = allFundings.filter(flatRatePredicate).asInstanceOf[List[AppliedFunding[FlatRate]]]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(flatRateFundings)
  }
}
```

Comment: In your case, `flatRateFundings` will still have the type `List[AppliedFunding[Funding]]` - it may contain the right objects, but the type is still the super-type.

Comment: Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: you can deconstruct it with patternmatching an either use `collect` or `foldX` to effectively filter by type. There are very few circumstances where `isInstanceOf` is required (besides for maybe performance or getting Any/Object from an external library)

Comment: I think complete deconstruction of every case class instance is an overkill for the filtering use case. I considered such variant, but could not persuade myself that it would be better than plain use of `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf`. I don't know how `asInstanceOf` works internally, maybe it is doing a similar deconstruction... Probably you have more knowledge, so I would be glad if you share.

Comment: mostly because it breaks parametericity. As I said I can imagine that performance considerations are an argument for a cast in this case but as long as it isn't I'd rather deconstruct. It is also quite possible that you can formulate the cases better with `@` or somesuch maybe?

Comment: Dominic, could you clarify what exactly you mean by "breaks parametericity"?

Comment: Thinking about it I'm no longer sure if it does in this case ( I just have a deep seated fear of casts :D ) . Parametericity is a property in functional programming that specifies that all versions of a polymorphic function behave the same. e.g. `def id[A](a:A) = ???` has only one valid implementation under parametericity that being `id[A](a:A) = a` if you were to e.g. cast a or check it's type and return something else, that property would be broken. Thus whenever I see casts I immediatly assume that parametericity no longer holds.

Comment: A note: try to desugar your code with `scalac -print` and you will see that pattern matching invocation used for deconstruction translates to `isInstanceOf` via `isDefinedAt` and `applyOrElse` for partial function used in collect